# How to delete all emails at once

Tags: gmail

I want to delete all mail from my gmail account. How can I do this all at once? I have over 3000 emails to delete. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to the all mail label by selecting all mail from the list on the left side of the page. If all mail isn't there it can be added under gear/settings/labels.
2. On the left side of the list are all the check boxes.
3. At the top of the list is a master checkbox pull down the list and select **ALL**
4. That will select every email on the page.
5. You will also notice a message on the top of the list **"All 100 conversations on this page are selected. Select all 3,456 conversations in All Mail"**
6. Click on the 2nd half of the message
7. Click the delete button at the top of the list of messages.